# How to use asyncio Semaphore in FastAPI to prevent asyncio loop error?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, aiohttp

I have the following code:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException
import creds
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from TokenManager import TokenManager

router = APIRouter()
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(1)
token_manager = TokenManager()

@router.post("/poderCompra/{comitente}")
async def poder_compra(
    comitente: str,
    token: str = Depends(token_manager.get_token)
):
    url = creds.URL_ROOT + "PoderCompra"

    async with semaphore:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            return await process_request(session, url, comitente, token)
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<RequestResponseCycle.run_asgi() running at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py:420> cb=[set.discard()]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

In my testing file I am doing 2 "simultaneous" request and I want my fastapi app to call process_request() "slowly" 1 by 1.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. We should be able to take your code and run it locally to reproduce the problem you're asking about. Minimally, we would need to see the top level Flask app, along with how you're running it. You should strip out anything not relevant to the problem.